# Component in privateRoute is not rendering until page reload

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, routes

I need to allow access to users depending on their assigned roles. Allowed urls list is fetched in 'urls' variable in privateRoute. But the list is not loaded directly after login. Once I refresh the page, it works fine.

I have routes defined in App.js as follows:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    static displayName = App.name;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/Logout' component={Logout} />
                <Route exact path='/Employee/AllEmployees' component={AllEmployee} />

                <PrivateRoute path='/Employee/Detail' authed={'/Employee/Detail'} component={EmployeeDetails} />
                <PrivateRoute path='/Employee/Detail/:empid' authed={'/Employee/Detail'} component={EmployeeDetails} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => {
    let urls=[]
    fetch('api/Common/sessionStatus')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data == true) {
                fetch('api/Common/getScreens')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(result => {
                        urls= result;
                    });
            }
        });

    return <Route {...rest}
        render={props => {
            if (urls.find(x => x === authed)) {
                return <Component {...props} />
            }
            return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/Employee/AllEmployees", state: { error: "Sorry! You don't have rights to access this page." } }} />
        }}
    />
}
```

I need the list to be loaded directly after login without reloading the page. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Maybe you can force the page reload automatically after login: `window.location.reload();`

Comment: I don't want to forcefully reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use react state management

something like:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => {
    const [urls, setUrls] = React.useState([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      fetch('api/Common/sessionStatus')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data == true) {
                fetch('api/Common/getScreens')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(setUrls);
            }
        });

   }, [setUrls]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Instead of `urls= result` --> `setUrls(result)`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the fetch logic inside componentDidMount. You can learn more about componentDidMount from react here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: At first I wrote it in componentDidMount(). Still list was not loading directly.